# Making a convex polyhedron with two sheets of paper

Tags: euclidean-geometry, 3d, polyhedra

Suppose that we have two sheets of paper $S,T$ and that each of $S,T$ is in the shape of a convex quadrilateral. Also, suppose that the length of the perimeter of $S$ equals that of $T$. (Note that $S$ and $T$ are not necessarily congruent.)

Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : If we make a convex polyhedron with these sheets of paper in the following way, then how can we find every possible number of the faces of a convex polyhedoron?
>
> (1) You can fold the paper along a line.
>
> (2) You can make a convex polyhedron by pasting them **at the edge**.

**Motivation & Example** : We can make a convex polyhedron with $10$ faces (see the figures below where $S$ and $T$ are congruent squares. Folded along red lines. Each red line crosses the midpoints of edges of the square.).

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $[image]

This may be the easiest example and it made me interested in the question above. Can anyone help?

**Update 1** : Letting $N_f$ be the number of the faces of the convex polyhedron, user achille hui showed that $N_f\le 12$, and that there are examples such that $N_f=4,5,6,8,10$.

**Update 2** : I found that a [snub disphenoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_disphenoid) is an example for $N_f=12$. ($S$ and $T$ are congruent parallelograms with $6$ equilateral triangles.)

**Update 3** : User achille hui showed an example for $N_f=7$.

**Update 4** : User David Speyer showed an example for $N_f=11$. Hence, we have only one case $N_f=9$ to check. [This page](http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/symmetry/polynum0.htm) has a partial list of Enneahedra (polyhedra with 9 faces).

**Update 5** : I have a *conjecture* that we can make the following polyhedron with $9$ faces. ($S$ and $T$ are not necessarily rectangles.)

[image]

**Update 6** : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158500/making-a-convex-polyhedron-with-two-sheets-of-paper).

**Update 7** : A polyhedron in the conjecture above given by $$A(a,b,0), B(a,c,0), C(-a,-b,0),D(-a,-c,0), $$$$E(d,e,f), F(g,h,i), G(-d,-e,f),H(-g,-h,i)$$ is *almost* what we desire (but it is not) where
$$a=-2.71,b=0.931273,c=-0.963719,d=-2.681359,e=0.4689,$$$$f=4.28591,g=-2.66066,h=-1.368,i=3.74971.$$

Hence, the conjecture seems true, but I don't know how to get a concrete example strictly.

Comment: The simplest examples are tetrahedron (#face = 4) and cuboid (#face = 6).

Comment: May we paste a sheet (partly) to itself?

Comment: @achillehui: Oh, you are right. I didn't notice them. Thanks.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: No, we may not.

Comment: @achillehui: Won't it work even when each of the face $BEF$ and the face $EFG$ belongs to a distinct paper? Maybe I don't think I can understand the rule well

Comment: This is your question. It is up to you to set the rule. However, if you allow such constructs, then $\mathcal{N}_f$ need not be bounded by $12$. One now need to consider the possibilities the common boundary of $S$ and $T$ will split somes faces of the resulting convex polyhedron.

Comment: @achillehui: Oh, sorry for my bad wording. I meant 'the rule' is 'the sum of angles $=2\pi$ requirement'. I meant that I cannot understand well why the example for $N_f=9$ won't work when each of the face $BEF$ and the face $EFG$ belongs to a distinct paper.

Comment: Oh, I got it! It is obvious! So, my examples are not possible...

Comment: Wow, you are persistent. I was thinking spending a few more days for the $\mathcal{N}_f = 9$ case before posing a bounty myself ;-p

Comment: @achillehui: Oh, really? You are persistent too:) Persistence must be needed to find the 'gold' from an enneahedra world:) I've already found some stones which look like gold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you glue $S$ and $T$ along their equal perimeters, the result is a unique convex polyhedron, an amazing result of Alexandrov. This theorem is described in many places, including [*Geometric Folding Algorithms: Linkages, Origami, Polyhedra*](http://gfalop.org/), Chapter 23, Section 3. It is, however, quite difficult in general to construct the unique polyhedron realized. I wrote a short high-level description of the algorithm of Bobenko and Izmestiev [here](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/papers.php#259):

[image: Bobenko]

---

Recently it has been established that their algorithm can be implemented in pseudopolynomial time: "A Pseudopolynomial Algorithm for Alexandrov's Theorem" ([arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.5030)).

Because $S$ and $T$ have the same perimeter, there are an infinite number of ways
those perimeters can be glued together, resulting in a continuum of polyhedra so realized. These continua have been studied in particular cases (cf. *Geometric Folding Algorithms*), but in general are not well-understood.

Comment: I'm so glad to know the information! So, you think my question may be hard to solve? Anyway, If you know any other helpful information to solve my question (each of $S,T$ is a convex quadrilateral and now I'm interested only in every possible number of the faces), could you please let me know it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer summarizing result from me and other users.

Let $\mathcal{N}_v$ and $\mathcal{N}_f$ be the number of vertices and faces for the
polyhedron formed by gluing two convex quadrilaterals. Since the time of Euclid, it is known that for any convex
polyhedron, the sum of angles between neighboring edges on a vertex is less than $2\pi$.
Assume the convex quadrilaterals does not partly paste back to itself,
any vertex of the resulting polyhedron must come from a vertex of one of the quadrilaterals. As a result, $\mathcal{N}_v \le 8$. According to this [site](http://www.numericana.com/data/polyhedra.htm), we have
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathcal{N}_v = 4 &\implies& \mathcal{N}_f = 4\\
\mathcal{N}_v = 5 &\implies& 5 \le \mathcal{N}_f \le 6\\
\mathcal{N}_v = 6 &\implies& 5 \le \mathcal{N}_f \le 8\\
\mathcal{N}_v = 7 &\implies& 6 \le \mathcal{N}_f \le 10\\
\mathcal{N}_v = 8 &\implies& 6 \le \mathcal{N}_f \le 12\\
\end{array}$$
This means the largest possible $\mathcal{N}_f$ is $12$. Following is a list
of $\mathcal{N}_f$ which we know how to realize.

- $\mathcal{N}_f = 4$. e.g. a tetrahedron.
- $\mathcal{N}_f = 5$. e.g. a [triangular prism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_prism) with a right angled triangle as base.
- $\mathcal{N}_f = 6$. e.g. a cube.
- $\mathcal{N}_f = 7$. e.g. for any $0 < u < 1$, $w > \sqrt{1-u^2}$, consider 
  the convex hull of following 6 points $\pm \vec{A}$, $\pm \vec{B}$, $\vec{C}$ and $\vec{D}$
  where 
  $$\begin{cases}
  \vec{A} &= (1,v,0)\\
  \vec{B} &= (1,-v,0)\\
  \vec{C} &= (u,v,w)\\
  \vec{D} &= (-u,-v,w)
  \end{cases}
  \quad\text{ and }\quad
  v = \frac{w\sqrt{(1-u^2)(w^2+(u-1)^2)}}{w^2+u^2-1}
  $$
  One can cut the resulting heptahedron along $\vec{A} \to \vec{C} \to \vec{B} \to -\vec{A} \to \vec{D} \to -\vec{B} \to \vec{A}$ and unfold the surface into two parallelograms.
  $\hspace1in$ [image: heptahedron from 2 convex quadrilateral]
- $\mathcal{N}_f = 8$. e.g. a "distorted" octahedron with vertices at 6 points
  $\pm \vec{A}, \pm \vec{B}, \pm \vec{C}$ where
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  \vec{A} &= (-1,\alpha,1),\\
  \vec{B} &= ( 2,0,1),\\
  \vec{C} &= (-1,-\alpha,1)
  \end{cases}
  \quad\text{ and }\quad
  \alpha = \frac{\sqrt{3(3+4\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{49+24\sqrt{5}})}}{2} \approx 1.1657187
  $$
  One can cut this "distorted" octahedron along 
  $\vec{A} \to -\vec{C} \to \vec{B} \to -\vec{A} \to \vec{C} \to -\vec{B} \to \vec{A}$ and unfold the surface into two kites.
  $\hspace1in$ [image: distored octahedron from 2 kite]
- $\mathcal{N}_f = 10.$ e.g. a [square antiprism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_antiprism) mentioned in the question. A concrete
  example is the one with following 8 vertices at
  $$\begin{cases}
  (\pm 1,\pm1,0),\\
  (\pm\sqrt{2},0,\beta),\\
  (0,\pm\sqrt{2},\beta)
  \end{cases}
  \quad\text{ where }\quad\beta = \sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)} \approx 0.9101797
  $$
- $\mathcal{N}_f = 11$. e.g. a family of $11$-hedra found by user David Speyer.
  For any $u > \delta = \sqrt{2}-1$ and $u \ne 1$, consider the convex hull formed by following $8$ points $\pm \vec{A}, \pm \vec{B}, \vec{C}, \vec{C'}, \vec{D},\vec{D}'$ at
  $$\begin{cases}
  \vec{A} &= (u,1,0)\\
  \vec{B} &= (u,-1,0)\\
  \vec{C},\vec{C}' &= (\pm p,0, q)\\
  \vec{D},\vec{D}' &= (0,\pm\sqrt{2},w)
  \end{cases}
  \quad\text{ where }\quad
  \begin{cases}
  w &= \sqrt{u^2 - \delta^2}\\
  p &= u + \frac{\sqrt{2}w^2-\delta u}{u^2+w^2}\\
  q &= \frac{(\sqrt{2}u+\delta)w}{u^2+w^2}\\
  \end{cases}$$
  It is a convex polyhedron with $11$-faces and if one cut it along
  $$\vec{A} \to \vec{C} \to \vec{B} \to \vec{D}' \to -\vec{A} \to \vec{C}' \to -\vec{B} \to \vec{D} \to \vec{A},$$ we can unfold the surface into two rectangles. When $u = 1$, the convex hull reduces to a square anti-prism which we have used as an example for $\mathcal{N} _f = 10$.
- $\mathcal{N}_f = 12$. e.g. a [snub disphenoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_disphenoid), an example found by user mathlove.

Combine all these, we only leave with the case $\mathcal{N}_f = 9$ to check.

Comment: I found that a snub disphenoid is an example for $N_f=12$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_disphenoid

Comment: @mathlove cool, three more 7,9,11 and we are done.

Comment: Yeah! No examples for $N_f=7,9,11$ can be seen in Johnson solids. Maybe we need to prove that there is no examples? but how...

Comment: @mathlove polyhedron from the prism family can have odd number of faces. I'm not convinced 7,9,11 are impossible. [this](http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/symmetry/poly4-7f.htm) has a list of all polyhedra with 4-7 faces. one might be able to find an example for 7 by staring at them long enough. I find the example for 5 this way ;-p

Comment: A great example for $N_f=7$! Could you please tell me how you got the example? It may be a hint for $N_f=9,11$.

Comment: @mathlove, topologically, this is the first heptahedron on the list I mentioned before. There are a few things we know, like the fold lines cannot intersect in the interior of a quadrilateral. If more than one fold lines intersect on the boundary, the other end must be a corner. This make some polyhedron on the list unlikely to be an example. After eliminating those, you concentrate on the rest and stare at them.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your nice observation! Facing difficulty without any helpful site with figures for $N_f=9,11$. For me, finding examples for them seems quite difficult.

Comment: @mathlove Have you looked at [this](http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/symmetry/polynum0.htm)? It has a partial list of Enneahedra (polyhedra with 9 faces).

Comment: No! Thank you so much!

Comment: From your example for $N_f=7$, I reached a conjecture which I added in the question, but I don't have any good idea to check if it is possible. I would like you to let me know how you reached the coordinates of the example for $N_f=7$. I've been trying to check using coordinates, but it failed with tedious calculation.

Comment: @mathlove I obtain the coordinates by first playing around the figure in the brain, guessing which sort of configurations looks promising. Writing expression for the sum of angles on the vertices and them plot them out to find the parameter range that actually works. I need to stare at your conjecture more before I can do anything ;-p

Comment: I reached a conjecture I added in the question. This may be what we want. I'll check if it is possible later.

Comment: When $u=1/2, w=1,$ the example for $N_f=7$ seems to be concave If I'm not mistaken. The edge $-\vec B \vec D$ seems to be concave.

Comment: In the example for $N_f=8$, letting $S$ be the convex quadrilateral $ABC(-B)$, could you please show me what the shape of $T$ is? I cannot get it.

Comment: @mathlove About $\mathcal{N}_f = 7$, it is convex. I have added a picture of it and if you look at that at suitable angle, it is obvious the edge $-\vec{B}\vec{D}$ is convex.

Comment: @mathlove About $\mathcal{N}_f = 8$, the cutting instruction I wrote down is wrong. The correct order should be $A(-C)B(-A)C(-B)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for adding the figures! For $N_f=7$, I was wrong. By the way, the conjecture for $N_f=9$ does not seem true though I cannot prove it is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can achieve $11$ faces by

[image]

as long as $2a < \sqrt{2} (a+b)$.

Comment: +1 Haven't figure out all the algebra. but randomly throwing in some numbers, the configuration does seem to produce something that works.

Comment: Thank you so much! Why $2a\lt \sqrt 2 (a+b)$?

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible that face $USQW$ is not flat in the polyhedron but rather slightly creased by one or the other diagonal?

Comment: achille hui wrote down what appear to be explicit 3D coordinates for it in his massive answer above. I convinced myself that it could be done by the following argument: There is definitely some angle at which I can fold along QS and UW to make points R and V be $2a$ apart. When I have folded QS and UW like this, but not touched QW and SU yet, then the angles RQP, PQV, VUT and TSR are obtuse. Raise P and T up to make those angles right. Then everything snaps into place, without creasing USQW.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Thanks, my doubt is dispelled!